# What happens if I delete the GPG key from my GitHub account?

Tags: git, github

I've previously used Git to sign Commit to all commits automatically using the GPG key. And the Git work is on GitHub. A few days ago, my computer suddenly screwed up and I reinstalled my OS. And soon I realized I did not back up my GPG private key. So I want to create a new GPG private / public key pair. Do I have to delete the GPG public key previously created and registered in GitHub? If I had to remove it, did the commits I have done previously fail to be verified?

Comment: You don’t have to delete your old one; just add the new one.

Comment: I deleted without reading any warnings and all my previous commits are showing as `unverified`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Previously verified commits will not be verified any longer if you delete the old key - Github cannot take a commit to be verified if it does not know the key used to sign it with.

There is no need to delete expired/lost keys as long as you are sure they did not get stolen. You can generate a new keypair and add the new public key on Github next to the old one. Deleting an old public key is advised if you suspect your private key to be compromised and are now afraid someone could use it to fake-sign potentially malicious commits or bypass software-validation mechanisms for your software.

Comment: Is this still the case today? just stumped upon this in their [docs](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/updating-an-expired-gpg-key): `Your previous commits and tags will show as verified, as long as the key meets all other verification requirements.`

Comment: The key can only be verified as long as Github knows it - correct me if I am wrong here. In any case it may not be revoked to be valid.

Comment: It's still valid - I've mistakenly removed my expired GPG key from GitHub, as well as from my local computer - now all the commits I signed before are shown as 'unverified' :/

Comment: If you still have the public key, you can add the public key back onto GitHub, and that will fix make all the unverified commits go back to being verified.